# Posting self-answered questions for information: Should they be community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, self-answer

I recently posted a question to SO in which I immediately answered myself because I figured it would be a common question about the newly released Windows Phone 8. Someone suggested I make my answer community wiki.

What do you think? Should my answer be community wiki to avoid the appearance of rep mongering or does it matter?

I know the whole community wiki controversy hasn't been addressed in quite a while, so...

Comment: Your question seems like it's rather poor.  What would you do if you saw someone else ask it sincerely?  "What are the system requirements for X system?" seems like something that that system should be readily providing.  It is in fact the case, the question can be answered with a simple link to the "system requirements" page for the download of that product.  A question that can best be answered by linking to a page, or copy-pasting a page's content and then linking to it, and that is likely to have very high ranking in a search engine, is a low quality question.

Comment: @Servy I considered it especially worthwhile to point out out that the Phone 8 emulator won't run inside a virtual machine, unless it's using an unsupported configuration of VMWare 9.

Comment: See, now that seems like it could be it's own question, "I'm trying to run this emulator in [...], but it's saying that [...], what's wrong", "That emulator won't run in an emulator, you need to run it on [...]."  That's valuable, and appropriately scoped.

Comment: @Servy well, that's what ended up happening. Someone ended up asking a question about running it in an emulator, so I copied-pasted my answer over to there and deleted my own answer from my question (and put a comment on the accepted answer). I think that's good style heh

Comment: Somewhat related post: [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/997587)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As an answer to [What can be done to improve moderation of self-answered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137353), Jeff Atwood suggested:

> One possible solution is to "unify" reputation in these cases so intentional self-answers (that is, answers that come in within 1 second of the question being posted) don't get rep for both the question and the answer, but just the answer. This would at least unify the incentives a bit and prevent the perception, correct or not, of double-dipping.

I was against it then and I'm against it now. Question and answer, whether posted by the same user or not, are two separate posts.

If somebody posts a horrible question with a brilliant answer, he deserves to lose rep for one and gain rep for the other. Likewise, if somebody writes a well-researched, clear and non-localized question and answers it himself, he deserves to get for both posts.

Artificially limiting the rep you can earn from it isn't consistent with the fact posting questions to answer them yourself is explicitly encouraged.

Comment: That was my thoughts exactly, but I hadn't seen someone pull the "you should community-wiki that" card on something since ~2010 and I wasn't for sure if attitudes have changed