# Should own solution be included within the question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I think its still in debate [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/151832)

Normally when I have a question and a answer, but have doubt with my own attempt, I tend to put the solution within my question. And I'll only post the question (if without a solution in my mind), and could post my solution afterwards separately as a answer to my own question (if I can found out one).

But today I met [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19222903/352101) and been enlightened to always post them separately, is this the case? Maybe its there but I really can't find it in FAQ, and even it is, I still feel a question for suggestions of your own answer should include the solution in the question.

Comment: See also: [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198727/should-i-ask-a-question-which-i-learned-its-answer-while-asking-it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a problem that needs solving, you need to indicate that you've attempted in some way to solve it yourself. Such an attempt goes in the question: this is what you've tried. This is standard fare.

If the purpose of a question is to showcase a solution to a problem that actually works<sup>1</sup> and answers the question fully, as opposed to an attempt at a solution that does not work, then the solution should be posted as an answer instead of being embedded in the question. This has never been debated.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Of course, if the answer doesn't actually solve the problem or is otherwise incorrect, it's liable to downvotes just as with any other incorrect or bad answer.</sub>

Comment: Get it, is this all in FAQ?

Comment: @Bolu: Yes, here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 4):

If you have an answer to your own question you should post it as an answer, not as a part of the question.

Questions belong in questions; answers belong in answers.

If others feel that your answer isn't a good one, that it doesn't work, or uses bad practices or otherwise should be used, they can use voting to reflect on that, and/or post competing answers to answer the question more effectively.  You using your own solution need not inhibit someone else from posting a solution that answers the question that is entirely unrelated to your answer.

If you're just looking to have your solution/answer reviewed, and aren't so much interested in someone else posting an entirely unrelated solution to your problem, you can post on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Very clear, PS:thank you for the cute panda :)

Comment: The link should point to codereview.stackexchange.com, there is a missing "e" in your link.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Fixed, thanks, although note that you could just suggest an edit to fix an obvious typo like that as well.

Comment: @Servy I would if I had the edit privilege, but right now I won't dummy 6 characters edit when only one is needed.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Editing that one character is determine by the diff formula as an edit to the whole word, and as such it's technically a 10 character edit.  Just look at the highlighting in the revision history.